# Create a matrix 11x3 with 0's and 1' s on each entry depending on the result of the condition, using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a matrix 11x3 with 0 and 1 and save it as the variable TIME. Each entry in the matrix will execute the following if u[i] < t then will give 1 as an entry else 0.

My code is the following:

```
u = [1, 3, 9]

ts = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,  8, 9, 10]

time = np.zeros((len(ts), len(u))) # the size of the matrix 
for i in range(len(ts)):
    for j in range(len(u)):
        for t in ts:
             if u[j] < t:
               time [i,j] += 1
             else:
               time[i,j] += 0
               print(time[i,j])
```

However I do not get the result I  want. If anyone could help I would be grateful. I want to create a function out of it because I want to use it again later on my code but it does not work .If anyone could help I would be grateful.

Comment: What result do you want and what result do you get?

Comment: Please fix the second line of your comment. Rather that "does not work", explain what is actually happening.

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation. It's off in at least two places.

Comment: When asking about Python, use the plain Python tag in addition to the version tag. There is nothing really version specific about your question.

Comment: All of these issues can be fixed with the edit button below your question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for the comments. I will work on them. I know the indentation is off in almost every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using nested [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutoarrayrial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehensions#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
import numpy as np

u = [1, 3, 9]
ts = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,  8, 9, 10]

l = [[int(x < y) for x in u] for y in ts]
time = np.array(l)
print(time)
```

Output will look like this:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what I had in mind to do and I was failing..nested list comprehensions... thank you!